# Akka cluster node version compatibility

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

What is garanty between akka cluster version compatibility?
E.g. is it safe to start different nodes of a cluster with different akka verions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general running a cluster with nodes on different versions of your software (let alone of Akka) is not recommended: it will be complicated to avoid compatibility problems between the nodes. If you want them to evolve independently it might be worth considering turning them independent applications and communicating via a well-defined application-level protocol.

That said, we are careful to keep wire compatibility such that rolling upgrades are always possible. For larger releases there may be some things you will have to take care of to ensure a smooth upgrade, see for example [these considerations when upgrading from 2.4.x to 2.5.x](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#rolling-update).